# Degree of compositum $[LK:K]=[L:L\cap K]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be fields contained in a field $M$. Is it true that $[LK:K]=[L:L\cap K]$? I thought about taking a $(L\cap K)$-basis of $L$ and proving that it is a $K$-basis of $LK$, but that doesn't seem to work.

If this is not true, which assumptions do we have to add? (I know that it is true for Galois extensions).

Comment: In prop 3.18 of Milne's notes on Field Theory, this is proven assuming K is Galois over some ground field.

Comment: Let $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5\,)$ and $K=\Bbb Q(\omega\sqrt[3]5\,)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Then $LK=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,\omega)$ and $L\cap K=\Bbb Q$. So $[LK:K]=2$ and $[L:L\cap K]=3$. Equality when one of the extensions is Galois, that’s called the Theorem on Natural Irrationalities.